# Delete a background from a photo

Tags: gimp, background-removal

I cannot select just the plate in this photo as the colours are so similar, I have put alpha on selection and tried colour and fuzzy select and path but I cannot do it well because of all the curves, is there another method? sorry this is the first time I have tried GIMP[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture is very blurry, so using a path is the only practical solution.

This is fairly quick (about 5mn) when you are used to the tool:

[image]

Results:

Scaled down

[image]

Full scale detail:

[image]

PS: this demonstrates that a bit of care when taking the picture goes a very long way towards making editing easier. The same plate on a dark and uniform background (never use cloth, unless it is very dark), with a sharp focus would be amenable to most other selection tools.